# I am getting Syntax error in sql (insert)

Tags: sql, database, h2

So, I am trying to add a data if a value in field does not exist. I am keep getting syntax error and not sure where I am getting it wrong.

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY_TABLE(company_name, company_phone, company_url)
VALUES ('test','010-4843-0000','www.company.com')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM COMPANY_TABLE WHERE company_name = 'test');
```

This is my code.
I am using H2 database

Comment: What is the error message? (append to the question) ... also, add a tag for the DB vendor (MySQL, sqlite, etc)  that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to combine a *values* table constructor with syntax of a *select* query

You can insert into a table using *select*:

```
INSERT INTO COMPANY_TABLE(company_name, company_phone, company_url)
SELECT 'test','010-4843-0000','www.company.com'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM COMPANY_TABLE WHERE company_name = 'test');
```